# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void date() from the type Date

Tags: date, execute-anonymous

As per the title, I am encountering this issue when running an anonymous apex script:

```
List <ServiceContract> serviceContractList = [SELECT Id, Status__c, Status FROM ServiceContract WHERE Status__c = 'Active'];

for(ServiceContract sc : serviceContractList) {
    if(sc.Next_Payment_Date__c != null && sc.Next_Payment_Date__c == Date.today()){
        sc.Cancellation_Request_Date__c = Date.today().addMonths(1).addDays(-1);
        sc.Cancellation_Reason__c = 'Others';
        sc.Other_Reason__c = 'DIWM Decommission';
        sc.EndDate = Date.today().addMonths(1);
    }
    else if(sc.Next_Payment_Date__c != null && sc.Next_Payment_Date__c != Date.today()){
        sc.Cancellation_Request_Date__c = sc.Next_Payment_Date__c.date().addDays(-1);
        sc.Cancellation_Reason__c = 'Others';
        sc.Other_Reason__c = 'DIWM Decommission';
        sc.EndDate = sc.Next_Payment_Date__c.date().addDays(-1);
    }
    else{
        sc.Cancellation_Request_Date__c = Date.Today();
        sc.Cancellation_Reason__c = 'Others';
        sc.Other_Reason__c = 'DIWM Decommission';
        sc.EndDate = Date.Today();
    }
}

Database.SaveResult[] saveResultList = Database.update(serviceContractList, false);
for(Database.SaveResult resultList : saveResultList) {
    if(!resultList.isSuccess()) {
        for(Database.Error e : resultList.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');
            System.debug(e.getStatusCode() + ': ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The error is here: sc.Cancellation_Request_Date__c = sc.Next_Payment_Date__c.date().addDays(-1);

the error may also be here: sc.EndDate = sc.Next_Payment_Date__c.date().addDays(-1);

My question is, how do I add days to a date field without encountering this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex has two shortcuts, an overloaded `+` and `-` operator:

```
sc.Cancellation_Request_Date__c = sc.Next_Payment_Date__c - 1; // Subtract a day
```

Further, a `Date` is already a `Date`, which is why it has no `date()` method. You can use it directly:

```
sc.Cancellation_Request_Date__c = sc.Next_Payment_Date__c.addDays(-1);
```

Comment: Thank you, worked

Comment: @JaemyMalik Of course, always happy to help!